# Python Excel writing values from csv starting at 2nd column

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I'm using XLWT to write excel files from .csv and I have the first column in the csv as the style for the row. How can I start writing the values beginning with the second column of each row (as to not print out the value, for example, "headerStyle")? I've tried a few different ways, such as creating a col_count but haven't had any luck.

```
row_count = 0
style = rowStyle

#Read each row and write to sheet
for row in csv_input:
        #Iterate through each column
        for col in range(len(row)):
            if col == 0:
                style = row[col]
            else:
                if(is_number(row[col]) == True):
                    sheet.write(row_count,col,float(row[col]),style)
                else:
                    sheet.write(row_count,col,row[col],style)

        #Increment row_count
        row_count += 1
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

I ended up figuring it out. For anyone interested, one problem was that style was coming back as a string so I created a function to fix that:

```
def assign_style(string):
    if string=='headerStyle':
        style = headerStyle
        return style
```

Then the following would loop through while skipping the first column:

```
    row_count = 0

#Read each row and write to sheet
for row in csv_input:
        #Iterate through each column
        for col in range(len(row)):
            if col == 0:
                style = assign_style(row[col])
            elif(is_number(row[col]) == True):
                sheet.write(row_count,col-1,float(row[col]),style)
            else:
                sheet.write(row_count,col-1,row[col],style)      
        #Increment row_count
        row_count += 1
```

Comment: What is the output you get with the code you've posted? Also, bear in mind that sheet.write is 0-indexed, so with your code the second column in the CSV (i.e. the first column of data) will be written to column B in the spreadsheet.

Comment: You're right, I got around that by doing col-1 in the sheet.write statement. I figured it out, solution is above if you're interested. Thanks!

Comment: This question is obviously a follow-on from your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414521/how-do-i-apply-a-style-to-the-whole-row-using-xlwt-python-excel ... Your current solution of pre-computing the style to be used and writing that to your csv file is an astonishing kludge. See my answer to your previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `iter()`. Also, don't iterate over the `range()`. Instead use `enumerate()`. And use the ternary operator, it helps to maintain DRY:

```
for row_count, row in enumerate(csv_input):
    columns = iter(row)
    style = next(columns)
    for col_count, col in enumerate(columns, start=1):
        sheet.write(
            row_count,
            col_count,
            float(col) if is_number(col) else col,
            style
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up doing it a different way but yours looks promising. Something I could use in the future!